# Connect BroadcastReceivers

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a broadcast receiver class, which I want to connect to a broadcast receiver in the main activity class, in order to call a method which originally called the broadcast receiver CLASS.

I have been struggling to find out how this would be done, and I think I am over complicating things. I saw something about using registerReceiver in the main activity class, but I don't think this is what I want.

This is the code setup in case I confused you.

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            restartAlarm();
        }
    }
    private void restartAlarm(){
        //Do some stuff and call the RecursionReceiver class
    }
}
```

RecursionReceiver.class

```
public class RecursionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Somehow call the broadcast receiver in the main class
    }
}
```

EDIT: I will provide some more details.

What I am trying to do is set an alarm that will trigger at a certain point, which will call the broadcast receiver class. This class should in turn call the reset alarm method, which will reset the alarm.

No, I can't use a repeating alarm for what I want. This is because I am setting another alarm that requires this alarm. The other alarm will be set to trigger at a certain time, plus or minus a random number of milliseconds. It should not trigger at the same interval. However, I need it to start after the same period of time. So if I have that alarm to trigger every day at 6pm and want a offset of + or - 60000 milliseconds (one minute), the alarm will trigger within the boundaries. I have accomplished this, but I need a way to reset the alarm at the desired time, not at the trigger time. Plus I need to redo calculations to change the offset time.

My solution to this is have a second alarm that does nothing but recall the method to start both alarms at the time when the offset alarm SHOULD reset. If there is an easier way to set the second utility alarm, then let me know. Otherwise, I am confused about how to recall the method in the activity class from a broadcast receiver class.

The solution I found said I needed to do it with registerReceiver and have a BroadcastReceiver in the activity class. Then I could activate the receiver from the one that the alarm calls, and call the method from the receiver in the same class as the method. But there was no explanation for the code and it has highly confused me.

I am confused on how to make the receiver work from inside the class. I have made external broadcastreceivers work, but not local ones.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve, and I think it would be good if you gave more context and code. In any case, it seems weird that you would want this recursion with your broadcast receiver, and I bet there is another way to do it. Either way, in order to have the broadcast receiver called you need to register it (programmatically or in manifest) and then fire an intent that will have it start.

Comment: I added a bit more context and explanation in the post, sorry for being unclear.

Comment: You could have resetAlarm live as a static method in RecursionReceiver. Then your activity will call that static method, and that will trigger RecursionReceiver for the first time. Then RecursionReceiver.onRecieve will call the static method when it wants to re-trigger itself.

Comment: My method that I intend to call cannot be static because of methods inside such as getSystemService(blah);

Comment: You can receive a context in the static method, and make these calls on it

Comment: Are you tellinge I'm wrong or trying to suggest a solution? I'm not around to try, which is why I'm asking. If you are correcting me, then maybe it's a different method. I don't remember perfectly. But I am confident that something didn't like bein g in the static method.